# Git store infor.cfg file for different branches

Tags: git, config, branch

My project is an express webserver. I have two different branches (master and dev).

The master webserver listens port 80. (const port = config.PORT)
The dev one 8080. (const port = config.PORT)

I store many information in a server.cfg file. How can I save the changes on each branch in the same file without getting merge complications?

Adding in .gitignore was not the right way.

Comment: You can't.  Either store them in separate files and symlink to (or copy) the appropriate one or use some other technique, like LeGEC recommended, preferably using the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can store both in your config file, and have an external flag tell the program what section to use.

For example :

- in your config file, store  `port = 80` in the `[main]` section and `port = 8080` in the `[dev]` section
- if your server is launched with the `-dev` option, or if `MODE=dev` is set in the environment, use the `[dev]` section to verwrite values in the `[main]` section